# Flask - database items not being created with form submission

Tags: python, forms, flask

I'm trying to have users submit comments on a project through the project's page (not through a separate comments route).

This code is in my __init__.py folder. I have a route for each project, and I repeat the `@app.route` code for the comment function. However, when I click submit on the template, nothing happens.

```
@app.route("/projects/<int:project_id>/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def project_detail(project_id):
    project = db.session.query(Project).get(project_id)
    all_comments = db.session.query(ProjectComment).filter_by(project_id=project_id)
    if project is None:
        abort(404)
    return render_template("project_detail.html", project=project, all_comments=all_comments)

@app.route("/projects/<int:project_id>/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def comment(project_id):
    project = db.session.query(Project).get(project_id)
    all_comments = db.session.query(ProjectComment).filter_by(project_id=project_id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("project_detail.html", project=project, all_comments=all_comments)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        new_comment = ProjectComment(
            member_id = current_user.id,
            project_id = project_id,
            content = request.form.get("content"),
            #time_created = now
            )
        db.session.add(new_comment)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("project_detail.html", project=project, all_comments=all_comments)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: `I click submit on the template, nothing happens` Does page reload? If not then form is not being submitted.

Comment: Can you show us the html form?

Answer (score 1):

You *don't* need to repeat the code for the route function. you can just make it one route and check if the method is get or post.

Comment: I think the problem is that when the HTML form is submitted it only finds the first route ( which is not handling the submission ) and so it doesn't search for the one that is handling the submission.